# How to make background color as boxshadow color while hovering

Tags: javascript, sass

I want to make the background color of the h4 as boxshadow color while hovering, how can I do that in scss [make background color as the boxshadow color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXao4.png)

I applied this color

```
&:hover{
         box-shadow: 20px 20px 60px #a49898,
         -20px -20px 60px #decece;
}
```

Comment: Your code seems to be SCSS/SASS, not pure CSS. Are you using SCSS/SASS?

Comment: yes exactly, I am using scss @AndersKjeldsen

Answer (score 0):

if you mean to apply a radial gradient background effect, this is the rule you're looking for:

```
&:hover {
    background: radial-gradient(#decece, #a49898);
}
```

if you meant like the background of "HTML\CSS\Java..[..]" in your picture, it's gonna be just:

```
&:hover {
    background-color: #decece;
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it does not work

Comment: is there a background set also for the normal state? it could be a specificity issue.
(this means at ex. selector div.container will be read over selector .container as it's more specific)